# How do you add a code block to a pull request description on github?

Tags: github, pull-request

Typing HTML does not work when I want to show a Code Block.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the **[documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/#fenced-code-blocks)**, use a triple backticks on its own line. Optionally, you can add the language next to it in order to activate the syntax highlighting mode.

````
```ruby
require 'redcarpet'
markdown = Redcarpet.new("Hello World!")
puts markdown.to_html
```
````